# find interval of convergence for series

Tags: power-series

Is it right that the range of convergence is here $1 < x < 3$:

$$\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{e^n + e^{-n}}{n^2} (x-2)^n$$

Just like you do with the geometric series? Or what is this radius of convergence? Thanks!

update:

i got until now:

$$\frac{\frac{(e^{n+1}+e^{-(n+1)})*(x-2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}}{\frac{(e^n+e^{-n})*(x-2)^n}{n^2}}$$

(the middle fractal line should be the main one)
and this should be less the 1

right?

Comment: Actually, a ratio test might be a good idea here...

Comment: ok, thx, i check out what that is

Comment: @Chilango: I think the radius is slightly wider than $0$, but (obviously) smaller than $2$.

Comment: Yes you are right. I misread the problem!

Comment: Bonus question: can you include the boundaries in the convergence interval?

Comment: How about writing the general term as  $\frac{2\cosh n(x-2)^{n}}{n^{2}}$, and then apply the limit comparison test, using L'Hospital twice

Comment: first things first :)   so, if i do this ratio test, i divide n+1th element by n-th element, right? now i'm not sure if I have to take as an element the whole formula or just the (x-2)^n

Comment: The former, i.e. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(e^{n+1}+e^{-n-1})n^2|x-2|}{(e^n+e^{-n})(n+1)^2}<1$

Comment: too bad... looks not good :)

Comment: but i don't get your formula neither, with the absolute value, and the -n-1, should'nt it be like -(n-1) ?

Comment: made an update, pls have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Ratio Test, we have

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{n+1}+e^{-(n+1)}}{(n+1)^2}\lvert x-2\rvert^{n+1}\cdot\frac{n^2}{(e^n+e^{-n})\lvert x-2\rvert^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{n+1}+e^{-(n+1)}}{e^n+e^{-n}}\cdot\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\cdot\lvert x-2\rvert$

$\displaystyle=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e+e^{(-2n+1)}}{1+e^{-2n}}\cdot\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^2\cdot\lvert x-2\rvert=e\cdot 1\cdot\lvert x-2\rvert=e\lvert x-2\rvert$,

and $e\lvert x-2\rvert<1 \iff \lvert x-2\rvert<\frac{1}{e}$.

---

To test convergence at the endpoints of the interval,

A) $\;\displaystyle x=2+\frac{1}{e}$ gives the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1+e^{-2n}}{n^2}$,

$\;\;\;$which converges by comparing to $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ using the Limit Comparison Test.

B) $\;\displaystyle x=2-\frac{1}{e}$ gives the series
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{1+e^{-2n}}{n^2}$,

$\;\;\;$which converges since its absolute value converges.

Therefore the series converges for x in $\displaystyle\left[2-\frac{1}{e},2+\frac{1}{e}\right]$.

Comment: Is $|x-2|\lt \frac 1e$ strictly necessary, or is it possible that we have $\le$?

Comment: ok thanks!  the absolute value I still don't understand, but i will think it through tomorrow morning, but now I can't even see any more...

Comment: @abiessu: is it like if we derive this analog from the geometric series, than it can't be equal to 1 cause then it would be a division by 0, right?

Comment: @abiessu Good question - I have only found the open interval of convergence, so I will edit my answer to test the endpoints.

Comment: @user3435407: that would be true if we had only a geometric-type series, but we have the $1\over n^2$ portion as well...

Comment: ok, got everything, thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

According to WolframAlpha, the interval of convergence is as follows.

[image: Radius of Convergence]

You can see it plotted as so:

[image: Plot of interval of convergence]

Unfortunately I'm not sure how one would go about finding it, but for the bottom  part you can use the p-series test and because it is n^2, p>2 so it is convergent everywhere, now you just have to decide for the top part what test to use.